# I can't connect HTML file to CSS stylesheet on GitHub

Tags: html, css, github

here are my GitHub files:

**removed**

The files all worked well locally, but problems appeared when I uploaded the code on GitHub. I even discovered that some html link tags didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the link tags are all pointing to the wrong link, they should point to `Egypt.css` not `egypt.css` or `resources\css\egypt.css`

Answer (score 1):

Check your links as the CSS link is not pointing the right file `<link href="resources\css\egypt.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">` there is no file at such location.
doing this will solve your error `<link href="./Egypt.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: thank you! does capitalization matter when referring to source files, locally on pc and on github?

Comment: no, it must not matter. Here, the problem was your path to the file which was incorrect.